# How to install Cartthrob 3 in EE3?

Tags: cartthrob

I've just purchased cartthrob 3 and weirdly their documentation only covers installing on EE2. Has anyone had any success installing a fresh version of cartthrob 3 onto a new EE3 site? If so, how did you do it please?

Comment: Is it not the standard? So the add-on (mod.cartthrob.php etc) goes into system/user/addons/cartthrob and the supporting frontend files go into themes/user/cartthrob (css, js & images)

Comment: Kind of. Anyway, I got it to work in the end - I hadn't put an encription key in the config.php file. I have to say I emailed cartthrob and they got back to me pretty quickly and sorted it. Top darts.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm with Vector; we own CartThrob)

As @Moonage mentioned in a comment, this is all resolved now. The issue was a missing encryption key in the configuration files. I'm glad we got it figured out!